# Django: admin login with parameter

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

I want to have my custom "`/login`" page. So in `settings.py` I did a simple `LOGIN_URL = '/login'`. But before doing it, I want to develop all other more complex pages. I found a simple but very effective hack like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # blabla
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', RedirectView.as_view(
            url=reverse_lazy('admin:login'))),
    # blabla
]
```

This means: when the user is not connected he/she is redirected to `/login`. In the urls, `/login` is converted to `'admin:login'` which is `admin/login`. This is a "double" redirect. Everthing works fine except this:

- origin URL: "`/my_jobs`"
- redirected to "`login?next=/my_jobs`"
- redirected to "`/admin/login`"

So my problem is that I want do pass **again** the "`next`" parameter in the `RedirectView`. I found a lot about redirection and custom login, but not something about that on stackoverflow (this is not a duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`query_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.query_string) to `True`, so that query strings are appended to the URL.

```
RedirectView(
    url=reverse_lazy('admin:login'),
    query_string=True,
    # You might want to set permanent=False, 
    # as it defaults to True for Django < 1.9
    permanent=False, 
)
```

Note that Django comes with a built in [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) view. You can enable it by adding the URL pattern and a simple template, which isn't much more work than your code above.

Comment: It's *that* simple... i've been fighting for that for 2 hours now... thank you very much

Comment: I would use the [built in logout view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.logout) rather than trying to redirect to the admin logout view.